# how to set image to a div on mouse over on top of everything?

Tags: html, css

I am doing some css stuff,

Now I have a div tag slimier to this.

```
<div class="myDivClass">
<img src="some image url">
<h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

Now I need to add hover to that div class. What I need to do is When mouse over happening Another image should appear on top of that image,

ie. [image]

But both of them should be displayed and closed image should only appear when mouse over.

CSS :

```
.myDivClass:hover{

  content:url(closed image url);

}
```

Thanks in advanced..!

Comment: What have you already tried with css?

Comment: I have updated my answer after seeing your edit regarding the use of `content`. it is used with pseudo elements.

Comment: if anyone seeing this question useful please vote

Comment: @SachithSenarathne: The bigger question is, did *you* find it and the answer(s) useful?

Comment: @abhitalks Now yes. your answer gave me the solution. And Thanks every one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position your images within the `div` by making the `div` itself as relatively positioned.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/9GBUF/***

*HTML*:

```
<div class="myDivClass">
    <img class="baseimg" src="...">
    <img class="overlay" src="...">
    
<h2>Title</h2>

</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
div.myDivClass {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
}
div.myDivClass img.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}
div.myDivClass:hover img.overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

---

### Update: (After Op's Edit)

If you want to do it using a pseudo-element, then also you need to position it.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Z93t7/1/***

*HTML*:

```
<div class="myDivClass">
    <img class="baseimg" src="...">
<h2>Title</h2>

</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
div.myDivClass {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
}

div.myDivClass::before {
    content: url(...);
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%; left: 0px;
    display: none;
}

div.myDivClass:hover::before {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.MyDivClass a:hover {
   background-image(closed image url);
}
```

This will change it for the specific div.
When you set a class for a div you need to call div in CSS.
The way you are using it currently .MyDivClass is trying to call it as a CssClass, not a div class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:absolute;` Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R63tq/)** to see if this is what you want.

For the html, you can add the image you want (the closed image) with the clase `closed`
**Html code:**

```
<div class="myDivClass">
    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png" />
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <img class="closed" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlPAH.jpg" />
</div>
```

For the css you need to add the `:hover` and give your image with the `closed` class a `postion:absolute;` and `display:none;` So it wont show until you hover the div. 
**Css code:**

```
.myDivClass:hover .closed{display:block;}    
.closed { 
     width:640px; 
     height:181px; 
     position:absolute; 
     top:100px; 
     display:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R63tq/)**

Answer (score 0):

Correct your css code for `hover`

```
div.myDivClass:hover
{
background-image:url(closed image url);
}
```

`content:url(closed image url);`,  you need to replace `content` with `background-image`.

Comment: `content` is **not** invalid css. it is used for pseudo-elements. you may want to remove that from your answer.

Comment: does content work if we do not use `::after` or `::before` @abhitalks

Comment: no. you may want to read this ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score 0):

my decision

**HTML**

```
<a class="demo" href="#">
<img class="raz" src="http://myubuntu.ru/images/12/mac-rename-title.jpg" />
<img class="dva" src="http://myubuntu.ru/cache/multithumb_thumbs/b_675_675_16777215_10_images_12_mac-scrollbars.jpg" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.demo { 
    position:relative; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    height: 400px;
    width:400px;
    display: block;
}

  .demo img { 
    left: 0; 
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0; 
}

  .demo img.raz {opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);}
  .demo:hover img.raz {opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);}
  .demo:hover img.dva, .demo img.dva:hover {opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);}
```

[live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FeEsx)

Comment: I have to keep both images

Answer (score 0):

.imgBox { width: 191px; height: 191px; background: url(http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/duck.png) no-repeat; } .imgBox:hover { width: 191px; height: 191px; background: url(http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/peng.png) no-repeat; }        - See more at: http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html#sthash.6X5XZ7k5.dpuf